# Better way to get a Julian date?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to Python. The following code works fine to take the current Julian date and subtract 90 days to get the Julian date for that day. I'm just curious if there is a better way to write this code?

```
    def jninety_date(self):
    today = int(time.strftime("%j"))
    year = int(time.strftime("%y"))
    jdate = today - 90
    if jdate <= 0:
        jdate = 365 - abs(jdate)
        year -= 1
        return "Julian Date: " + str(year) + " " + str(jdate)
    elif jdate < 99:
        return "Julian Date: " + str(year) + " 0" + str(jdate)
```

## returns 15 342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) instead. Following is the example.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt_90 = datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=90)
>>> dt_90
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 11, 14, 21, 70374)
>>> dt_90.strftime("%Y %d")
'2015 09'
```